# Create new Column in Power Bi with RegEx

Tags: powerbi, data-transform

I'm relatively new to Power BI and want to generate a new one based on a column. The contents of the new column should be based on the first value of another column. For example:

```
ColumnA NewColumn
1123 Argentinia
5644 Brazil
5555 Brazil
3334 Denmark
1124 Argentinia
```

As you can see, the first value of the number decides which country will be added to the new column. 
In SQL I know that I can use something like this:

```
`select * from table where column LIKE '%[2]`%'
```

and so on but is this possible with Power BI? Thanks a lot.

Edit:

My additional list looks like this:

```
ID Country
1  Argentina
2  Swiss
3  Denmark
4  Norway
5  Brazil
```

and so on...

I thougt I could use somethin like this:

```
NewColumn = IF('table'[ColumnA] = "%[1]`%" 
THEN "Argentinia"
ELSE if IF('table'[ColumnA] = "%[2]`%
THEN Swiss
ELSE "No Country")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have a second table which maps numbers to countries? What code have you currently tried?

Comment: No I have only a list with these numbers. But if it were easier, I could also use this data as a column. I have tried it with a IF ELSE Statement but I don't know exactly how I'm gonna use it.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to more clearly illustrate your requirement, what you've tried so far, and the specific problem you're having. If you do have a list which maps numbers to countries, then there are many methods which may be possible to join and identify the related country - but without a clearer description of your data and code, it's very difficult to give meaningful advice.

Comment: I'd also suggest removing `RegEx` from your question title - this has nothing to do with regular expressions, as far as I can see.

Comment: I hope with my edit is is now more understandable? As I have written I am relatively new at using power bi. Sorry!

Comment: @Tim1234 Import mode or direct query? If import connection I recommend the query editor. If direct query you will have to use `DAX`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've now also found a solution:

```
NewColumn = SWITCH(TRUE();

                 LEFT(table[ColumnA]; 1) in {"1"}; "Argentina";
                 LEFT(table[ColumnA]; 1) in {"2"}; "Swiss";
                 LEFT(table[ColumnA]; 1) in {"3"}; "Denmark";
                 LEFT(table[ColumnA]; 1) in {"4"}; "Norway";
                 LEFT(table[ColumnA]; 1) in {"5"}; "Brazil"
            )
```

Works very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your Number / Country List to a new table. Let's assume you call it `Countries`.

Now you can add a column to your original table (let's assume you've called that one `Fact Table`), using something like:

```
Country = 
LOOKUPVALUE ( 
    Countries[Country],
    Countries[ID],
    VALUE ( LEFT ( 'Fact Table'[ColumnA], 1 ) )
)
```

See https://pwrbi.com/so_56391689/ for worked example.